# make: Showing possible missing dependencies

Tags: gnu-make

I am working on a program that has a complex Makefile: Some of the source files are generated using some scripts.

The following simplified example shows my problem:

```
myProgram: example1.o example2.o
    gcc -o $@ example1.o example2.o

%.o: %.c example.h
    gcc -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.cc
    gcc -c $< -o $@

%.c: %.in generator
    ./generator $< $@

generator: generator.o
    gcc -o $@ $<
```

Not all files of my program are implemented, yet, and `make` reports:

```
No rule to make target 'example1.o', needed by 'myProgram'.
```

In the example, there are different possibilities for building `example1.o`:

- from `example1.cc`
- from `example1.c` and `example.h`
- from `example1.in` and `generator` and `example.h`
- from `example1.in` and `generator.c` and `example.h`
- from `example1.in` and `generator.cc` and `example.h`

Unfortunately, it is hard to keep the overview over my project, so I don't have the overview about which files are missing. Therefore, I'd like to get a list of missing dependencies - like this:

```
<some_command> example1.o

"example1.o" can be built from:
    example1.c (missing)
    example.h (present)
or:
    example1.cc (missing)

<some_command> example1.c

"example1.c" can be built from:
    generator (missing)
    example1.in (present)
```

(The tool does not need to search for dependencies recursively; I can do that manually.)

Question: Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: You could try what information `gmake -d` prints as debugging info (which is a lot) and massage the output.

Comment: @Jens Thanks. I already knew `make -qpr ...`. I decided to write some tool that evaluates the output of `make -qpr ...`: 460 lines C code and it's even showing recursive dependencies!